# embedded browser using XULRunner

Tags: browser, wxwidgets, embed, xulrunner

Are there any examples of to use XULRunner to embed the browser control inside a app? (preferably in c or c++ for native win32 apps)

I have tried QT, wxWidgets, Awesomium, chrome embedded, LLmozLib, midori and Embedding/NewApi/Win32

The best one is wxWebConnect (which is part of wxWidgets framework). Why, cause you don't need the whole mozilla code base to build it plus the actual browser control is perfect as in plugins work, everything is rendered correctly (gmail, youtube etc etc)

So what's my problem or question? Well the wxWebConnect uses XULRunner to embed the browser control, my application is native win32 app and not wxWidgets app. I've searched the net to find another example of how use XULRunner to embed the gecko browser in native win32 apps..without luck!

Anyone know of projects/code that just use XULRunner and not require the entire mozilla source tree?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of XULRunner-based applications at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner_Hall_of_Fame

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use wxWebConnect or embed XULRunner directly you are still going to have as part of your applications deployment the XULRunner engine and it's folder hierarchy. That's the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 0):

Try [GeckoFX](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/), if you are okay with using .NET. Looking at the GeckoFX code might also give you enough insights to embed xulrunner in your native C++ Win32 app.